# How do i make this discord bot to send message to specific channel?

Tags: python, discord, bots

i recently just make a this bot to send a message on my discord server. the bot works fine except this bot sending the message to the same text channel where i send the command from. i want to make this bot to be able to send a message to specific text channel meanwhile i send the command from a private text channel.
this is the code :

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="+")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('logged in as : ' + client.user.name)
    print("the announce bot is ready")

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def ann(ctx,message):
    channel = client.get_channel(ChannelID)
    embed=discord.Embed(title=f"ANNOUNCEMENT GUYS !",description=message,color=0x9208ea)
    embed.set_footer(text="Made by Fypo#0001")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

client.run("token")
```

i put the `channel = client.get_channel()` already but the bot keep sending the message to the same text channel where i send the command. anyone can help ?

Comment: In your own words, when you do `await ctx.send(embed=embed)`, what do you think the `ctx` part means? You wrote `ctx.send` and the message was sent to the original text channel. How do you think the `ann` function even knew such a channel existed? Can you think of a way the `ctx` value might be relevant to that?

Comment: "i put the channel = client.get_channel() already " Okay, so this *gets* you the `Channel` object. If you want to send to the corresponding channel, it makes sense that you should *use* that object in some way... right?

Comment: I found the linked duplicate by putting `discord.py send message to channel` into a search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you send message to the ctx. You should send it to the channel object you got with get_channel().

```py
await channel.send(embed=embed)
```